# Bar in ApexChart bar chart is covering the data label

Tags: vue.js, apexcharts

I am new to Vue and ApexCharts and trying to learn. I am trying to plot a bar chart where the bar does not cover the data label. I know this can be controlled by the "offsetX" value in chart option (as documented here: https://apexcharts.com/docs/datalabels/). However, it did not fix it. I'm assuming because of the big difference between numbers, the bar had to behave that way.

[image: This is how I want it to look]
[image: This is how it looks now]

Any help, please?
Thanks.

Comment: This is the default behavior. When the data-label cannot fit in the chart, it goes inside the bar instead of outside.

Comment: @junedchhipa I see. Is it possible to override this default behavior somehow?